# converting map to arraylist using stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I want to transform arraylist:

```
Transfer("111111", "222222", 100)
Transfer("111111", "222222", 100)
```

to another arrayList, but it is group by dAcc and cAcc

```
Transfer("111111", "222222", 200)
```

Below is the code, but I am not able to convert the map to Array List:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
       ArrayList<Transfer> transfers = new ArrayList<>();
        
        transfers.add(new Transfer("111111", "222222", 100));
        transfers.add(new Transfer("111111", "222222", 100));
        
        Map<String, Transfer> map = transfers.stream().collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                f -> f.getDAcc() + f.getCAcc(),
                Function.identity(),
                (s, a) -> new Transfer(s.getDAcc(), s.getCAcc(), s.getAmount() + a.getAmount()))
            ).values();
            
        System.out.println("Map:" + map);
     }
     
     public static class Transfer {
        private String dAcc;
        private String cAcc;
        private int amount;
        
        public String getDAcc() {
            return dAcc;
        }
        
        public String getCAcc() {
            return cAcc;
        }
        
        public int getAmount() {
            return amount;
        }
        
        public Transfer (String d, String c, int amount) {
            this.dAcc = d;
            this.cAcc = c;
            this.amount = amount;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the reduced `Transfer`s to a `List` you can do - `new ArrayList<>(map.values());`:

```
Map<String, Transfer> map = transfers.stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(
                f -> f.getDAcc() + f.getCAcc(),
                Function.identity(),
                (s, a) -> new Transfer(s.getDAcc(), s.getCAcc(), s.getAmount() + a.getAmount()))
);

System.out.println("Map: " + map);

List<Transfer> reducedTransfers = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

System.out.println("reducedTransfers: " + reducedTransfers);
```

Output:

```
Map: {111111222222=Transfer(dAcc=111111, cAcc=222222, amount=200)}
reducedTransfers: [Transfer(dAcc=111111, cAcc=222222, amount=200)]
```